# How to group by certain column then take the count of multiple columns where it is not NA and add them in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to do a group by the ID and then add the count of values in A and B where it is not NA then add the count of both A and B together. To add on to that, what if I want to count only the y values in A?

```
+----+---+---+
| ID | A | B |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | x | x |
|  1 | x | x |
|  1 | y |   |
|  2 | y | x |
|  2 | y |   |
|  2 | y | x |
|  2 | x | x |
|  3 | x | x |
|  3 |   | x |
|  3 | y | x |
+----+---+---+

+----+--------+
| ID | Output |
+----+--------+
|  1 |      3 |
|  2 |      6 |
|  3 |      4 |
+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do:

```
df = df.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: sum(pd.notna(x))).sum(1).reset_index(name='Output')

print(df)

   ID  Output
0   1     5.0
1   2     7.0
2   3     5.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if I would like to condition it further to where I would only want to add a certain value to the count if the character is 'y'? Please take a look at the updated table

Comment: just modify the condition inside `agg`, something like `lambda x: sum(x.eq(y))`